# Failure building Rust on linux with glibc 2.5

Tags: linux, rust

I am trying to build Rust for RHEL5 (Linux v2.6.18) with GNU C Library stable release version 2.5.

The pre-built bootstrap version of Rust, that is downloaded automatically when running the Rust make, is incompatible with glibc 2.5 -- I get the following error.

x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage0/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage0/bin/rustc)
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage0/bin/rustc: /lib64/libc.so.6: version`GLIBC_2.6' not found (required by x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage0/bin/rustc)

Unfortunately, upgrading glibc is not an option for the target OS

Is there any way for me to build Rust on my platform?

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to build a newer copy of gcc and glibc first. Don’t worry, you can use it only for Rust stuff (stick it in a different directory and add that directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` whenever running Rust things), but it does need some newer stuff.

Comment: building a newer copy of glibc is somewhat dangerous: it doesn't expect to be installed side by side another version last time I checked.